# SignalR Context.User.Name returns empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, signalr

Whenever I try to access `Context.User.Identity` from a `Hub`, the user details are always empty.

**Note:** Context.User does **not** return null, the properties are just empty:

[image: empty properties]

I've taken a look at a multitude of questions on SO similar to this, but all of them seem to be asking why the `Context.User` is `null`, and the answer is to move `app.MapSignalR();` below `ConfigureAuth();`, as I have done:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
```

The `HttpContext.Current.User` also returns empty, but again, only from within a `Hub`. If I call it from any other `Controller`, I get the currently logged in user details.

Finally, I also find it disturbing that `HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated` is `false`, yet the user can still access the function. (See the `Authorize` attribute in the screenshot above.)

Is anybody able to shed some light as to why my user is empty?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd recommend you to check claims - username could sit there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a go. (I see this being more of a work-around rather than a fix though!)

Comment: claims are empty too. they count the value but the actual data of value is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Set anoynomous to false and windows authentication to true