# User.Identity.GetUserId() returns null after successful login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I've defined a temp variable to get current user id, it always returns null.

Here is the snapshot:

[image: userId]

Why?

**UPDATE:**

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, ex = "Fail to login." });
        }

        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, isPersistent: true, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                return Json(new { success = true });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
                return Json(new { success = false, ex = "Email or password was incorrect." });
            default:
                return Json(new { success = false, ex = "Fail to login." });
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

On client side, I use ajax to connect to `/Account/Login`:

```
var loginAjax = function (email, password, callback) {        
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/Login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { Email: email, Password: password },
            success: function (data) {
                $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
                if (data.success) {                    
                    callback(true)
                } else {
                    $('#login-error').text(data.ex)
                }
            },
            error: function () {                
                $('#login-error').text('Không thể kết nối đến máy chủ.')
            }
        });
        callback(false)
    };


// I've got email and password in another function to check valid or not
loginAjax(email, password, function (success) {
            $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
            switch (success) {
                case true:
                    signin(function () {
                        $('.login').html('');
                        window.location.href = '/?type=Promotion';
                    });
                    break
                case false:                    
                    $('#Email-active').hide();
                    $('#Password-active').hide();
                    $('#Password').val('');
                    $('#login-btn').removeClass('disabled').attr('onclick', '$(this).addClass("disabled").removeAttr("onclick"); running()');
                    break
            }
        });
```

SignalR on client side:

```
var signalR = $.connection.chat;
var signin = function (callback) {
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                signalR.server.signinToSignalR();
                callback()
            })
        };
```

SignalR on server side:

```
public void SigninToSignalR()
    {
        // this's always null
        string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }
```

Comment: Please show your code as a text, not as an image.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Actually, the user is **not** signed in - not in the context of **the current request** *(the `POST /Account/Login` request)*, which is where `User.Identity` gets its data. If you want to extract the id of the user currently trying to *(and apparently succeeding)* to sign in, you need to do that in some other way, like hijacking some step inside the call to `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`. If you are implementing your own `MembershipProvider`, this should be easy.

Otherwise, you will have to wait for **the next request** *(any request handled by some Controller's Action method should do fine)* to use `User.Identity` in the way you want to.

## Some added explanation

When your `Login` method gets called, the request context is already evaluated and a lot of data is available. For example HTTP headers, cookies and so on. This is where all the context information is found, like `User.Identity`.

When you call `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(...)`, this does **not** affect the values of the **request context**, because this would make no sense – since the browser has not changed its mind about what it sent a few milliseconds ago. What it does affect is the **response context** to add a **cookie** containing some user and session id. This cookie is then sent to the browser, which then sends it back to server for each successive request. So all requests later than this one *(until the user signs out or the cookie gets too old)* will include information for the `User.Identity` to interpret.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain to me more about `the current request` and `the next request`? When is a request called `current request` or `next request`?

Comment: Well, that's just basic English and temporality. The "current" request is the HTTP request that your code is *currently* handling - in this case it's the `POST /Account/Login` request. By the "next" request I simply mean the next request to come in at some later point in time *(ranging from microseconds later to days later)*...

Comment: ya. I think something maybe wrong. I'll give you an example: On client side, I use ajax to connect to `/Account/Login`. After successfull login, I use ajax again to connecet to signalR hub (`/Hubs/ChatHub.cs`). I defined a method to get userId, but it's still null. `public void SigninToSignalR() { string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId(); }`

Comment: Then, I've tried to get userId in the View: `@{ string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();  }`. It's still null after refreshing the page.

Comment: For the SignalR case, this can be tricky. There is an answer here that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002092/context-user-identity-name-is-null-with-signalr-2-x-x-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Have you implemented your own `MembershipProvider`? In that case, what have you done with regards to `UserId`? I think the problem must be somewhere else. It looks like you are letting the user log in using an **ajax** request. Why? And what are you doing with the results on the client side? I think you need to update your question a bit.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I've solved it by double refreshing page. I don't know why but `User.Identity.GetUserId()` has been working after I do that. :)

Comment: This is the same reason why you need to do a redirect after logging out; logging out happens after the HTTP context has been constructed and if you issue a logout only the next request will actually be in a logged out context.

Answer (score 36):

Simply try this :

```
string userId = SignInManager
.AuthenticationManager
.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Comment: This is the best answer for this question

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Nice to get a solution rather than a long-winded explanation with very little actionable help

Comment: doesnt work.... shows there is no such extension methods.

Comment: AuthenticationResponseGrant is a property from IAuthenticationManager add by Microsoft.Owin (namespace :  Microsoft.Owin.Security)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt152207(v=vs.113)

Answer (score 12):

You could, in your case use other data to find the user that just logged in. Since we know that the login is successful and username is unique the following will work;

```
 //
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, ex = "Fail to login." });
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, isPersistent: true, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            string userId = UserManager.FindByName(model.Email)?.Id;
            return Json(new { success = true });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
            return Json(new { success = false, ex = "Email or password was incorrect." });
        default:
            return Json(new { success = false, ex = "Fail to login." });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
HttpContext.User = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
```

After signing in you can use the sign in manager to create the user principal and manually assign the HttpContext.User reference

This will then allow you to access the user id like you would with a normal signed in page

```
var userId = userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
```

Comment: I like this response since it ties in nicely with already having the user object in many cases.

Comment: I implemented Basic Auth and needed to access information about the user from `context` after signing in on the first POST. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as Anders said, User.Identity and User.IsInRole will not work inside the same login action.
So, You need to redirect to a new action, So inside login action add :

return RedirectToAction("MyNewLoginRoute", new {returnUrl=returnUrl });

below is a code example:

```
        var result =  SignInManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:

// below is the new line modification
      return RedirectToAction("LoginRoute", new {returnUrl=returnUrl });
```

And Now add a new action LoginRoute as below :

```
 // below method is new to get the UserId and Role
 public ActionResult LoginRoute(string returnUrl)  //this method is new
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
        {
            if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal("/Admin");
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("Partner"))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal("/Partner/Index/");
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("EndUser"))
            {
                ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            // know the partner
                int partnerID = db.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault().PartnersTBLID;
                return RedirectToLocal("/Partner/List/" + partnerID.ToString());
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
    }
```

Hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I get the user doing the following right after sign-in:

```
var userId = SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.GetUserId();
var user = SignInManager.UserManager.Users.Where(x => x.Id.Equals(userId)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

**For those who are implementing custom auth provider and still did not get it why User.Identity.GetUserId() is returning null after successful login**

You just need to add ClaimType.NameIdentifier while adding a claim, see below line:

> **`identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Email));`**

**Adding below code just for reference:**

```
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
      
      /*Following line(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier) is the reason to return UserId for User.Identity.GetUserId()*/
       identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Email));

      var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                        {
                            {
                                "UserName", user.Name
                            },
                            /*add more user info here*/
                         });

 var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
 context.Validated(ticket);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: true, rememberBrowser: false);

AuthenticationManager.User = new GenericPrincipal(AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity, null);
```

Once executed, you get authenticated state for the current request.