# User.Identity.GetUserId() returns null in AccountsController but works fine in HomeController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC5 ASP.NET C# application, I want to store some important but *temporary* data in the session. For that I tried to set the session on receipt of signin success as following:-

```
public class AccountController: Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
    .
    .
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.rememberMe, shouldLockout= false);

    switch (result){
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            var user =  UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        .
        .
        }
}
```

whilst this one fails , calling `User.Identity.GetUserId()` inside the `HomeController` return the correct result.

Can anyone please explain why this happens and how can get the **Current user** after Signing in so as to set the session.

**UPDATE**

I have now retrieved the User object by using method `UserManager.FindBynameAsync(model.UserName)`. However I still cannot figure out why the UserId is not available despite of SignIn success.

Comment: Probably `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` is not enough, instead, use something like `var user =  UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);`.

Comment: It is possible you've encoutered similar issue like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951881/user-identity-getuserid-returns-null-after-successful-login. `User.Identity` usually not work in the same login action, you'll have to wait until next request.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Thanks for prompt response. I also simultaneously discovered that from the function `SendCode(string returnUrl, bool rememberMe)` in `AccountsController`. I have updated my question now.

Comment: @Tetsuya  Wow, that post clears all my doubts. Please post your comment as the Answer so that I can accept it