# SignalR get User Identity when client makes a call ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a hub in which the client makes a server call every 5 seconds to check if they have any new tasks to do. I know I can get the hub to get the connection ID, but how can I make it get the User Identity / user ID when they make the call? or will the client have to pass that value in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [signalR - getting username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130590/signalr-getting-username)

Answer (score 0):

Getting the user is pretty easy out of the box. If you want to get any more information though, you'll need to come up with a solution to handle it yourself.

You can get the user identity by using this in your hub.

```
string name = User.Identity.Name;
```

or VB version

```
Dim name = User.Identity.Name
```